# Error while parsing JSON

Tags: android, json

I am new to Android development. I'm sending JSON data from Android to my PHP server. But I'm getting an error:

```
Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value `<br` of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject".
```

This is my PHP code:

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","custome234r","reswtdf123");
if (!$con)
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("customer_dd_test", $con);

$jsonFeedbackResult = $_REQUEST['results'];

$flagToOpenTicket = false;            

$arrResult = json_decode(stripslashes_deep($jsonFeedbackResult));

$feedbackname = $arrResult[0]['feedbackname'];
$email = $arrResult[0]['email'];

unset($arrResult[0]);
$finalArray = array_values($arrResult);
foreach($finalArray as $key => $arrQuestionWithAnswer)
{
    if($arrQuestionWithAnswer['answer'] == 'bad' || $arrQuestionWithAnswer['answer'] == 'worst')
    {
        $flagToOpenTicket = true;
        break;
    }
}

if($flagToOpenTicket)
{
    $insertQuery = 'INSERT INTO dev_ticket(email, feedbackname) VALUES'; 
    $insertQuery .= '("'.$email.'", "'.$feedbackname.'"),';
    $executeQuery = trim($insertQuery,',');
    mysql_query($executeQuery);

}
mysql_close($con);
print(json_encode(array('response'=>$feedbackname)));

?>
```

Comment: i have printed my php code for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you've got some HTML embedded, probably a PHP error/warning string. The response from the server must consist of **ONLY** the json data. Anything else will become part of the string and cause parse errors.

Take the exact url you're hitting in android and see what it brings up in a browser.